# Can sorting before grouping improve query performance in Mongo using the aggregate framework?

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, indexing, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to aggregate data for 100 accounts for a 14-15 month period, grouping by year and month.

However, the query performance is horrible as it takes 22-27 seconds. There are currently over 15 million records in the collection and I've got an index on the match criteria and can see using `explain()` that the optimizer uses it.

I tried adding another index on the sort criteria in the query below and after adding the index, the query now takes over 50 seconds! This happens even after I remove the sort from the query.

I'm extremely confused. I thought because grouping can't utilize an index, that if the collection was sorted beforehand, then the grouping could be much faster. Is this assumption correct? If not, what other options do I have? I can bear the query performance to be as much as 5 seconds but nothing more than that.

```
//Document Structure
{
    Acc: 1,
    UIC: true,
    date: ISODate("2015-12-01T05:00:00Z"),
    y: 2015
    mm: 12
    value: 22.3 
}

//Query
db.MyCollection.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "UIC" : true, "Acc" : { "$in" : [1, 2, 3, ..., 99, 100] }, "date" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-12-01T05:00:00Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2017-02-01T05:00:00Z") } } }, 
    //{ "$sort" : { "UIC" : 1, "Acc" : 1, "y" : -1, "mm" : 1 } }, 
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "Num" : "$Num", "Year" : "$y", "Month" : "$mm" }, "Sum" : { "$sum" : "$value" } } }
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest you to do is to make a script (can be in nodejs) that aggregates the data in a different collection. When you have these long queries, what's advisable is to make a different collection containing the aggregation data and query from that.

My second advice would be to create a composed index in this aggregated collection and search by regular expression. In your case I would make an index containing `accountId:period`. For example, for account 1, and February of 2016, The index would be something like `1:201602`.

Then you would be able to perform queries using regular expressions by account and timestamp. Like as if you wanted the registers for 2016 of account 1, you could do something like:

`db.aggregatedCollection.find{_id : \1:2016\})`

Hope my answer was helpful